# Body is giving undefined when attempting to send fetch() request from React

Tags: reactjs, rest, http, request

I am attempting to send a `POST` request via `fetch()` to a backend service that I've written from React. My code for the request is:

```
var options = {
    method: 'post',
    body: '{"foo":"bar"}',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
  }

var request = new Request('/autocomplete', options)
```

However, when I try to send the request, I get a 500 error from my backend service. Turns out that the body is giving `undefined`. When I `console.log(request.url, request.method, request.body, request.mode)` I get:

```
http://localhost:3000/autocomplete POST undefined no-cors
```

I'm really confused because this was working before. I restart my server, and all of the sudden it's broken. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Can you share some of the code for `Request`?

Comment: Yeh, that would be massively helpful. However, I'd hazard a guess that your Request method is looking for an actual object being passed into body. Try killing the single quotes around it and just passing the object in.

Comment: did you solve it? I stumbled upon a similar situation